# what should I use after "improvement"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

> In 2014, the organization of the “media-capital” prize in the business
>   journalism field is the main project focused on improvement the
>   financial literacy of the population.

Or can you help me to structure this sentence correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either "focused on the improvement of {something}" or "focused on improving {something}".

Comment: Thank you. And is the other part of the sentence correct?

Comment: No. Is this a translation job?

Comment: it was an exercise